# How to scale our multiplayer support, similar to Among Us

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer

We are a small team with the goal of creating our first multiplayer game, and we want to support multiplayer that can rapidly scale up as Among Us has successfully done.

We don't have a huge budget and we are struggling to find an appropriate way to implement multiplayer, including peer to peer (although it would be exhausting to combat cheating and make a smooth experience). Our game has no more, no less than 50 players in a very tight space.

As an example, we're looking at the indie game Among Us. They went from such a small game with barely any players, to maintaining well over 3 million CCU (concurrent users). How can we achieve similar scalability?

Comment: This is a very broad question. There are a lot of things you can do to make your architecture more scalable, but most things I could post might not even apply to you or be things you already implemented. Can you be more specific? Is there some specific aspect of your architecture which makes you worry about not being scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck: game servers scalability is relatively straightforward nowadays and not that expensive. All major cloud providers today offer both fully-managed Kubernetes and serverless environments, all with auto-scaling so that you can only pay for what you need and use. The system will easily scale up and down, serving a hundred or a billion CCU seamlessly.

Now, what to choose among those services depends on how your backend works, how it's built. For instance, if you are on Photon Server, you have already a ton of options and Azure would be the best fit as a cloud provider. If you are on SmartFox Server then you should go for a managed Kubernetes, so just pick any of your liking among AWS, Azure and GCP. If your server is running on a headless instance of Unity then is a tad more complicated because of the way Unity works, so you must run separate servers for lobbies/matchmaking logic and actual games. Otherwise, scalability and user experience will go down the drain. This because Unity is a game engine, not a backend server, while the others I mentioned were designed to be backend servers: it's a matter of architecture.

One more thing you have to take into account is the regional separation. If your game is either turn-based or in case it can take a tad of additional latency; then you can get away with a single region. Otherwise, you have to go for at least two regional servers, Europe and the Americas. Maybe you need also Asia, depending on your users' distribution across macro-regions.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing my whole homework, tons of things I've gotta study, since I am new to networking and I've got pretty paranoid seeing so many independent games crushed for underestimating price/maintaining for multiplayer with a relatively low playerbase. Our game is generally meant to be just exploration with some interaction, less than Among Us for sure, but meant to support up to 200 people per session and estimated to go viral very quick, expanding to let's say 50 000 CCU, each split upon sessions of 200 players each.

Comment: I have done my research, Among Us uses https://github.com/willardf/Hazel-Networking on a Linode dedicated server. What do you think? Is it safe to emulate this? Or go all P2P?

Comment: Hazel is only a networking library, you still need to have a server to connect. Dedicated servers cost money and are hard to manage, so I always advise against it unless you know very well what you are doing and you are prepared to put money in it. Managed cloud is always better and you don't have to bother about scaling. If you have no server yet, then my suggestion is to go for SmartFox Server 2X: it's easy to scale, easy to manage and with the elastic licensing is very affordable (besides the fact that 100CCU are just free).

Comment: Look at who are SmartFox customers, so you understand the class of product I'm talking about: https://www.smartfoxserver.com/showcase/customers

Comment: That is indeed true as the main developer is into a constant battle with the server issues. I was very seriously considering SmartFox as I've read very good things about it all across the web. Our direction is pretty much clear at this point. I wish I could upvote your posts a thousand times. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)